# Difference for SELECT querys speed between these indexes: *UNIQUE(col1, col2)* vs *FK(col1), FK(col2)*

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance

**UNIQUE(col1, col2)** vs **FK(col1), FK(col2)**

I currently have both indexes enabled, and I don't really care much about de foreign relationship per sé. So I wonder if by having all those keys I'm getting redundant indexes for reading performance, or are they different in some edge cases?

I know these two columns are a good candidate for a primary key, but as a team we all decided to always have an autoincremental as a Primary key.

Comment: If this is a many-to-many table, see the advice here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL wants to create a separate index for each of these.  So you might have three indexes on :

- `(col1, col2)`
- `(col1)`
- `(col2)`

I say "might" because MySQL also tries to optimize the automatic index creation.  So, if the first index is already created, then the second is not needed -- they are redundant.  The third is needed, though.

My recommendation?  The automatic index creation supports other purposes -- enforcing a unique constraint for the first index or enforcing foreign key constraints for the second and third.  You want the database to do all of these.  Keep the `unique` and `foreign key` declarations!

So, the only thing you can do is ensure that the unique index is known about *before* the foreign keys are declared.  It should be sufficient to declare it in the `create table` -- however, I would put the `unique` constraint before the foreign key constraints just to be sure.

Comment: MYSQL automatically rearranges my **create table** so that the UNIQUE index is declared before my foreign keys, even when I declared it last. Tested in MYSQL 8

Comment: @madacol . . . Interesting.  So explicit index creation seems to be prioritized over implicit creation from a declared foreign key.

Comment: Didn't understand what you said, but just to be clear, when I said **foreign keys**, I meant to say **foreign keys' index**. So UNIQUE indexes always end up declared before normal indexes. I tested altering tables and creating tables from scratch, with a single column UNIQUE and multiple column UNIQUE, MYSQL always rearranges so that UNIQUE KEYs are after PRIMARY KEY but before normal KEYs